How to advertize a VNC server using UPnP?
I'm toying with an idea of reviving the MirrorLink standard by implementing it with Linux, because my car doesn't support andoid auto and I don't want to replace the unit just for that.
I found the MirrorLink documentation
Accoording to which I should establish a TCP connection between the ML client (car radio) and server (smartphone) and use UPnP to advertize which VNC based apps I can use. (If I understand correctly)
Right now I have a Raspberry Pi running RPi OS acting as a MirrorLink server (smartphone). I have a DHCP server up and running and I can see my car gets an IP address. MirrorLink uses VNC to display contents on the car's touchscreen, So I have a VNC server running on the standard port.
My problem is lack of UPnP knowledge. Here's a quote from the documentation:

The VNC Server start-up is automatically facilitated via UPnP. The MirrorLink Server's VNC Server shall be running,
when launching any application in response to a UPnP TmApplicationServer:1 service LaunchApplication action, as
defined in [4]. The LaunchApplication action shall return with a URL to the VNC Server, hosting the VNC session.
If the returned URL is already used from any established VNC session, this session will continue without any change.
Otherwise a new VNC session shall be established, given the following steps:

VNC Server shall listen for the VNC Client to make TCP connection at the provided URL.
VNC Client shall make a TCP connection to the provided URL.
VNC Server and Client shall initialize the VNC session according to the VNC protocol.


I think I can manage to write the xml file thats a description for the service I want to advertise over UPnP but I don't know how to actually advertize it on a local network. Only tutorials I could find were for using UPnP with media streaming or for port forwarding. I assume there may be some library that can help? Is it maybe possible with apache2?
I would be grateful for:

any informations about how to advertise services over UPnP on a local network
any feedback on terms that I used incorrectly

